# How to create a proper calculation of a due date in a dynamic manner in laravel

Tags: laravel

I been analyzing the proper calculation of the duedate for my app. I am working with a lending app where I need to display the due date for the borrower.

let say the approved date of their loan is 2019-10-27 and today is 11-5-2019. the payment scheme is dynamic. depending on what the admin set. in this example, the payment scheme weekly so I just need to say;

```
$duedate = date('M d Y', strtotime($loan_application->date_approval. ' + '.$loan_application->scheme->num_days.' days') );
```

from my example above the due date is supposedly on Nov 3, 2019. Now how can I make it say that the next due date is on Nov 10, 2019?

I really tried to analyze, here's my thought.

I get the difference between the approval date and NOW()

```
$diff = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loan_application->date_approval))->diff(Carbon::now())->days;
```

now I compared the $diff with $loan_application->scheme->num_days. so let say the $diff=9 and $loan_application->scheme->num_days = 7

now I created the condition

```
if ($diff > $loan_application->scheme->num_days) {
     //should display 
     Nov 10, 2019
     //because the current date is already Nov 5
}
```

and after Nov 10, + 7 days again, and + 7 days again and so on.

here is the complete code I already have;

```
$dateApproved = Carbon::parse($loan_application->date_approval)->toFormattedDateString();
$now = Carbon::today('M d Y');
$duedate = date('M d Y', strtotime($loan_application->date_approval. ' + '.$loan_application->scheme->num_days.' days') );

$diff = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loan_application->date_approval))->diff(Carbon::now())->days;

$numOfScheme = $loan_application->loanDuration->num_days / $loan_application->scheme->num_days;

if ($diff > $loan_application->scheme->num_days) {

}
```

I hope you understand my question. Please help. Thank you so much in advance.

this will add number of days from payment scheme. in my example 7 days. but how can I tell my code that today is already 2 days late, add additional 7 days

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took some time but I understood your question.

```php
$date_approval = Carbon::createFromTimestamp(strtotime($loan_application->date_approval));
$scheme_numdays = $loan_application->scheme->num_days;

$days = (intdiv($date_approval->diff(Carbon::now())->days , $scheme_numdays) + 1) * $scheme_numdays

$due_date = $date_approval->addDays($days)->format('M d Y');
```

[`intdiv`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.intdiv.php) is just php's integer division.

Comment: It works @IGP!!! I still absorbing your answer. Don't know yet how and why it works hahaha, thank you so much!